# giving the error "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

```
sw.Start();
System.Net.FileWebResponse res = (FileWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
sw.Stop();

TimeSpan timeToLoad = sw.Elapsed;
TextBox2.Text = timeToLoad.ToString().Trim();

var a=1.1;
a = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text); //This is where the error is thrown

var threshold=5;

if (a > threshold)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scale up server");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scale down web server");
}
```

Comment: This is a *terrible* question, you haven't even indicated which line its on (though I have a pretty good guess....) Try do to *some* research please. Googling that error should get you a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, it looks like you have an invalid string entered in the textbox. For example, entering "foo" in the textbox which will result in an exception since you're doing `Convert.ToDouble("foo")` .

Use `.TryParse`

```
var a = 1.1;
if (Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out a)) {
    var threshold = 5;
    if (a > threshold) {
        Console.WriteLine("Scale up server");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Scale down web server");
    }
}
```

Explanation: [Double.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) checks if the string value is convertible to `Double` or not and returns a bool. It will also write the value in the `out` parameter for us to use.

Comment: Hey thankxxx alot it worked but what is the meaning of the statement which u wrote above????

Comment: @GurjotSingh - explanation added

Comment: @GurjotSingh More importantly, it won't throw if the conversion fails which `Parse` (which is what `Convert.ToDouble` uses) will do (that exact exception no less....)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text) part

```
var a=1.1;
Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to compare the Ticks elapsed rather than the Entire TimeSpan, the below code snippet should save you from erroring out

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan t = sw.Elapsed;
        double v =0;
        Double.TryParse(t, out v);
```

and if you would want the ticks or another property you can use the properties on TimeSpan as well

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan t = sw.Elapsed;
        double v =0;
        Double.TryParse(t.Ticks, v);
```